# DocumentDB - Cannot compare two paths in query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Microsoft Azure Documents BadRequestException An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) that are not range-indexed. Consider adding allow scan header in the request.

My query is:

```
SELECT c.id FROM users c WHERE (c.lat < 29.89)
```

OVER ?? number of documents (as there are no way to get the number of document in collection with DocumentDB)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you are querying? I'm guessing users.lat isn't something that's comparable. Are you sure they're not strings?

Comment: {
  "lat": -65.6583190150559,
  "lon": -74.98864685185254,
  "age": 45.79291892424226,
  "cat": 32,
  "id": "f6a82cae-8f57-a9a4-d741-6c9054b2c4ec"
}

Comment: that are not range-indexed ? maybe should I add special options ? I use nodejs require('documentdb').DocumentClient, options: { masterKey:  {authKey}}

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the blogpost here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/27/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-2/

> Indexing Policy Tip #3: Specify range index path type for all paths
>   used in range queries
>
> DocumentDB currently supports two index path types: Hash and Range.
>   Choosing an index path type of Hash enables efficient equality
>   queries. Choosing an index type of Range enables range queries (using
>   `>, <, >=, <=)`.

It gives an example in C# to add a Range Index to make the path comparable, but there is similar functionality in the [node.js library.](http://dl.windowsazure.com/documentDB/nodedocs/global.html#IndexType)

When you create a collection, you can pass the IndexingPolicy through the body parameter. The `IndexingPolicy` has a couple of members. One of which is the IncludedPaths, where you can define indices.

```
var policy = { 
   Automatic: true,
   IndexingMode: 'Lazy',
   IncludedPaths: [
      {
      IndexType: "Range",
      Path: "path to be indexed (c.lat)",
      NempericPrecission: "1",
      StringPrecission: "1"
      }
   ],
   ExcludedPaths: []
}

client.createCollection(
  '#yourdblink', 
  { 
    id: 10001, 
    indexingPolicy: policy 
  });
```

Comment: How to Choosing an index type of Range from NodeJs request ?

Comment: You do that when you specify your indexing policy. This has to be done in code, it can't be done in the admin portal.

Comment: Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Policy can be changed in the new Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com), under (your DocumentDB resource) -> Settings -> Indexing Policy.